"Expanding Window Effect" scroll trigger, expanding div acting as transition into website Gsap? Js? React?
I am trying to make a scroll trigger transition similar to example below. A div acts like a portal/window where the user is able to look through into it and see the content behind it. As the user scrolls down the portal grows eventually covering the entire screen/viewport, and the website functions as usual after that.
https://www.playground.it/en (load in and scroll down you'll see the effect)
1st "the user initially see's a small window to the content behind"
2nd "as the user scrolls down the window expands, exposing more of the content below"
3rd "as the user continues to scroll down the window expands and covers the entire screen/viewport"
Methods I tried,

Initially i used normal divs, made them circle and used javascript to make it expand, however i realised i cant make a div transparent, and the area with content surrounding it to dissapear after the div grown and

I tried to make a div with a circular cut out assuming as it grows the cut out will eventually remove everything that was initially on that cutout div, however this didnt seem to work as i couldnt make a div with a circular center cut out.

Eventually i used svgs, along with clip path, this is where i got closest to the effect. i used a invisible svg and made it grow with gsap clip path by increasing the percentage, this had the desired effect however, the reason im here is the effect is not as smooth. When scrolling fast all the content is instantly exposed and the circle cut out dosent move in a sense "block by bloc" similar to the example instead it acts with a gsap duration hence it isnt smooth.


as a summary i have gotten the effect however, it is not smooth and i would like to know if they are any other methods i can try to make it animate block by block similar to the example.

Please show us relevant code, preferably as a runnable snippet. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Could you also explain a bit more about expanding block by block when you also talk about a circle? If you just want to expand it as a circle then you could have it with a square container and gradually expand that with border radius 50%, no blocks involved.

@AHaworth Thanks for the reply! , I am currently using an expanding circle as an proof of concept. Currently i am expanding the circle using gsap clip path with a duration. If you scroll down super fast on my code it skips past the effect "Not smooth". However on the site example site their expanding window dosen't expand based on duration, rather it expands based on each scroll, hence no matter how fast you scroll the effect will still be visible. So it feels like their expanding window "block by block" when u scroll. My code (codepen.io/eechern/pen/jOgBzBP)

Video showing what i mean (https://youtu.be/cYDxaRhVydw?si=7vEKmnWrJN8V1m4x)
.
As u can see when i scroll fast on my page it skips the animation, however on the example site no matter how fast the animation plays out, and their animation is not based on duration however expands "block by block". Thanks so much for your help. @AHaworth

If it were me I'd not bother with GSAP or any other library and instead take over the scroll event, perhaps with also a bit of timing, and have complete control on how fast the circle was expanding (or blocks being added).
